# Configure production application settings in .net core razor pages (appsettings.Production.json)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration, razor-pages, appsettings

My .net core razor pages web application runs well in debug mode (hosted on localhost), and fails once I publish it to IIS.

The issue comes from my application settings, specifically my production application settings. As part of my debug process I copied the json from appsettings.Development.json to appsettings.Production.json (after publish) which allowed my web app run without issue. That workaround is not satisfactory since I would have to manually replace this every time I publish.

appsettings.Production.json is not stored in the file directory/solution explorer. Instead it is created during the publish. I believe this is happening in Program.cs:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            //I believe that the configuration happens below:
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Here are my current json files. Note the priority for settings is user secrets --> appsettings.{EnvironmentName}.json --> appsettings.json. Meaning any duplicate keys will take the value from the higher priority file. In my case appsettings.json is used by both Development and by Production as a base set of settings, and the connection strings (from Dev/Prod) are added.

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Identity": "Server=server1;Database=Identity;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; user id=uName; password=12345678",
    "Logistics": "Server=server1;Database=Logistics;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; user id=uName; password=12345678"
  }}
```

and here is the appsettings.production.json file that is created:
**appsettings.Production.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Identity": "Server=server1;Database=Identity;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "Logistics": "Server=server1;Database=Logistics;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

How can I control/manually configure appsettings.production.json?

Comment: Sorry I can't catch you well. Did you mean that You have trouble to switch the appsetting.json file between test and production environment? Or something else?

Comment: Yes that is true. My development settings work, but the production settings are auto-generated and they don't work. The connection strings are the same in either case - I just need to be able to write to the production settings!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that will work for my purposes.

I have created another file called appsettings.Custom.json, with the configuration settings that I need.

Then I made the following changes:

1. In Properties --> Publish Profiles --> launchSettings.json I changed the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "Custom"
2. In Program.cs I added the following code to include the newly created appsettings.Custom.json file to the project. Note I cannot manually add appsettings.production.json - it gets overwritten on publish.

   ```
   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       //Begin added code for proper app config:
       .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
       {
           config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Custom.json");
       })
       //End 
       .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
       webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
   });
   ```

During debug I get the **Custom** environment and the **custom** configuration, published version gets **Production** environment, and **custom** configuration. Note that I added a key ("TestValues") value ("...from appsettings.Custom..." pair to my json for debugging purposes.

**Localhost version (debug from VS 2019)**

```
IWebHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName = "Custom"
IConfiguration.GetValue<string>("TestValues") = "Test Values from AppSettings.Custom.json"
```

**Published version**

```
IWebHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName = "Production"
IConfiguration.GetValue<string>("TestValues") = "Test Values from AppSettings.Custom.json"
```